# QGIS Processing Plugin: Setting input and output directory

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I would like to connect my input and output directories, as well as my input file 'boundary layer' within my processing plugin.
My plugin appears like this:

[image]

My plugin.py file is depicted below:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon

from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsApplication, Qgis, QgsProject
import processing
from .GET_provider import GETProvider
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication

cmd_folder = os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]

if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, cmd_folder)


class GETPlugin(object):
        
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.provider = None
        self.iface = iface
        #self.dlg =GETDialog()
        #self.dlg.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.reproject)

    def initProcessing(self):
        """Init Processing provider for QGIS >= 3.8."""
        self.provider = GETProvider()
        QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(self.provider)

    def initGui(self):
        self.initProcessing()
        
        icon = os.path.join(os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'logo.png'))
        self.action_1 = QAction(
           QIcon(icon),
           u"GE_S", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action_1.triggered.connect(self.runAlg_1)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&GE", self.action_1)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action_1)


        self.action_2 = QAction(
           QIcon(icon),
           u"GE_CD", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action_2.triggered.connect(self.runAlg_2)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&GE", self.action_2)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action_2)

    def unload(self):
        QgsApplication.processingRegistry().removeProvider(self.provider)
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(u"&GE", self.action_1)
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(u"&GE", self.action_2)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action_1)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action_2)
        
    def runAlg_1(self):
        processing.execAlgorithmDialog("GE:GE_S")

    def runAlg_2(self):
        processing.execAlgorithmDialog("GE:GE_CD")
            
    def reproject(self):
        data_dir = "C:/Downloads/Inputs"
        output_dir="C:/Downloads/Outputs"
        filename = "Boundary.shp"
        Boundary = os.path.join(data_dir,filename)

        filename = "RT_LE07_L1TP_194051_20001024_20170209_01_T1_2000-10-24_B3.tif"
        Landsat_Image1_NIR= os.path.join(data_dir, filename)
        processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:warpreproject",{'INPUT':Landsat_Image1_NIR,'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32630'),'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':os.path.join(output_dir,'Landsat_Image1_NIR_repr.tif')})
```

My script which I want to run is under 'def reproject' (I just want to reproject this file).
How do I connect my input and output directories and my boundary layer with the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: The easiest way to connect the two aspects, is to first create the interface in Qt designer, name all features and connect them with .clicked.connect()